# Titanium Mobile local notification crashes

Tags: iphone, mobile, notifications, local, titanium

I have a problem with local notifications. App crashes when trying to get back in app with local notification.
I copied the Kitchen Sink sample but modified a bit the bg.js.
In bg.js, there is something like this:

```
  Titanium.App.addEventListener('whatever', function(e){

  var myNotification = Titanium.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    alertBody: msg_body,
    alertAction: "Yup",
    userInfo: {"key": "value"},
    date:new Date(new Date().getTime())
  });

 });
```

Well, this is not my exact code, but this is the spirit. I tried to remove everything useless, but can't find the answer...
Here is the crash report header: https://gist.github.com/956064
Is this is a somewhat documented problem?

EDIT: typo in code.

Comment: does the kitchenSink background example run in your environment?

Comment: Yes, it works. But it works once, 3 seconds after getting in background. The main difference is my notification is launched on app event...

Comment: Is your event triggered to go off in the bg?

Comment: My event is triggered while in the background. When I receive a "direct message" in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak one way or the other to your use of an event listener, but the core problem here is the application crashing.  This is caused because you are creating multiple localNotifications with the same variable name. The solution to your problem is to ensure that you do not use the same variable name each time you schedule a localNotification, so use something like an array instead.  I had the same problem and it was a 30 second fix to toss the definition into an array, as such:

```
notification[n] = Titanium.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({ 
alertBody:"alert body",
alertAction:"View App",
userInfo:{"hello":"world"},
date:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3000) // 3 seconds after backgrounding
});
n++;
```

Comment: I'll try that this week and come back to you! Thanks!

Comment: Just for those who may struggle, here's a little more code:
`var n = 0;
var alertCount = 0;
var notification = [];

function notify(resp) {
 // This creates the notification alert on a 'paused' app
 notification[n] = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
  alertBody:resp,
  alertAction:"View App",
  userInfo:{"hello":"world"},
  badge:n+1,
  date:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3000)
 });
 n++;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `userInfo` field is not filled, which causes an exception in NCFDictionary. Assigning an empty object `{}` to `userInfo` solves the issue:

```
var notification = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
        date : date,
        alertBody : 'The alert!',
        alertAction : 'Launch now',
        repeat : 'daily',
        userInfo : {}           // <------- This line!
    });
```